# How to read exact N chars with Parsec?

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm new to Haskell and Parsec.
I wish to parse php-serialize format of string 's:numb:"string";' like

s:12:"123";6789012";

where number is count of chars.
So, function looks like:

```
newtype PhpString = PhpString String

pString :: GenParser Char st PhpString
pString = do { string "s:"
        ; value1 <- many1 digit
        ; string ":\""
        ; value2 <- takeExactNChars (read value1) 
        ; string "\";"      
        ; return $ PhpString value2
    }
    where 
        takeExactNChars n = ???????
```

Comment: Parsec has a combinator called `count` which does exactly this. It is equivalent to `replicateM`.

Comment: @Sarah nice, I didn't know about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would write it using `replicateM` from Control.Monad:

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import Control.Monad (replicateM)

pString :: Parser String
pString = do string "s:"
             n <- fmap read (many1 digit)
             string ":\""         -- Bug fix; you weren't picking up the colon
             s <- replicateM n anyChar
             string "\";"
             return s
```

Testing it in ghci:

```
*Main> parse pString "" "s:12:\"123\";6789012\";"
Right "123\";6789012"
```

Answer (score 9):

As Sarah mentioned, the idiomatic `parsec` solution is to use the `count` combinator:

```
newtype PhpString = PhpString String

pString :: Parser PhpString
pString = do
  string "s:"
  value1 <- many1 digit
  string ":\""
  value2 <- count (read value1) 
  string "\";"      
  return $ PhpString value2
```

We can go a bit further and clean this parser up to be a bit more succinct too, if that interests you:

```
import Control.Applicative (empty)
import Text.Read

pString :: Parser PhpString
pString = do
  len <- readMaybe <$> (string "s:" *> many1 digit)
  case len of
    Just n -> PhpString <$> string ":\"" *> count n anyChar <* string "\";"
    Nothing -> empty
```

Or perhaps even:

```
pString :: Parser PhpString
pString =
  readMaybe <$> (string "s:" *> many1 digit) >>=
    maybe empty $ \n ->
      PhpString <$> string ":\"" *> count n anyChar <* string "\";"
```

`empty` from `Control.Alternative` fails the parser, in case the `read` fails.

Comment: You can make it even more succint by using `Just n <- readMaybe <$> (string "s:" *> many1 digit)`, as pattern failure in the monad is the same as `mzero`.